# UAA How to create identity zone admin

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

We are using UAA's Multitenancy Functionality to our customers. 
As such, we required to create an identity zone for each customer to manage individual customers' information.

However, based on the documentation, I'm unable to locate how could I create an `identity zone admin` with the scope of `zone.<zoneid>.admin` and obtain this admin token.

```
Name    Description
Authorization   Access token with scim.write or uaa.admin scope required
X-Identity-Zone-Id  May include this header to administer another zone if using zones.<zoneId>.admin or uaa.admin scope against the default UAA zone.
X-Identity-Zone-Subdomain   If using a zones.<zoneId>.admin scope/token, indicates what Identity Zone this request goes to by supplying a subdomain.
```

[Create User API Reference Link](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/api/uaa/version/74.18.0/index.html#list-with-attribute-filtering)

Is there any guideline or guidance that we could reference?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/develop/docs/UAA-APIs.rst#sequential-example-of-creating-a-zone-and-creating-an-admin-client-in-that-zone?

Comment: @DanielMikusa, thanks for pointing out. Totally missed out this portion. It works!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

#### Target and get a token as the admin client

```
uaac target http://localhost:8080/uaa    
uaac token client get admin -s adminsecret
```

#### Update your admin client

This is to make sure it has the correct scopes, you'd only need to do this once.

```
uaac client update admin --authorities "uaa.admin,clients.read,clients.write,clients.secret,scim.read,scim.write,clients.admin,zones.write"
```

Then get a new token, which will have the scopes just added.

```
uaac token client get admin -s adminsecret
```

#### Create the zone and add the admin client to the zone:

```
uaac -t curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" --data '{ "id":"testzone1", "subdomain":"testzone1", "name":"The Twiglet Zone[testzone1]", "version":0, "description":"Like the Twilight Zone but tastier[testzone1]."}' /identity-zones
uaac -t curl -H "X-Identity-Zone-Id:testzone1" -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H"Accept:application/json" --data '{ "client_id" : "admin", "client_secret" : "adminsecret", "scope" : ["uaa.none"], "resource_ids" : ["none"], "authorities" : ["uaa.admin","clients.read","clients.write","clients.secret","scim.read","scim.write","clients.admin"], "authorized_grant_types" : ["client_credentials"]}' /oauth/clients
```

#### Target the zone & get a token as the admin client in that zone:

```
uaac target http://testzone1.localhost:8080/uaa    
uaac token client get admin -s adminsecret
uaac token decode
```

Reference: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/develop/docs/UAA-APIs.rst#sequential-example-of-creating-a-zone-and-creating-an-admin-client-in-that-zone